# Setting Slider value rounds off

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity's slider to set a floating point number between the ranges of 1.0 - 10.0. The problem is, it rounds off. I do not want the slider to round off the value, instead it should display as it is. Can you please help me fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

private Slider sliderUI;

void Start () {

        sliderUI = GetComponent<Slider> ();
        sliderUI.value = 3.56f;
}
```

The slider value changes to 3.6. How do I make it 3.56?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it only rounds it on the inspector, the component should have the value you give it.

Try adding an `Update` with `Debug.Log(sliderUI.value);`

If it is showing `2.6` you have a real problem, if it shows `2.56` then is just a visual for the inspector.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No unfortunately it still shows 2.6. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I will update with screenshots

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using?

Comment: It was the version issue. I downgraded from the latest one to an older version and that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure, but maybe you need to set the minimum to 1.00 and the maximum to 10.00 instead of 1.0 and 10.0 ot just 1 and 10.